# Positioning a movie clip over still images using green screen

Tags: movie-clip-editor, chromakey

I have managed to make a clip of myself and used greenscreen effectively. I have two issues that im struggling to sort out

1. I am doing an advice clip on property where I have greenscreened myself talking through the points. I want to be able to move myself to the right of the screen to not obstruct the stills that are background and showing the parts of a house i am talking about. I can only seem to move the whole screen

thank you

Comment: I suggest you post two different questions, since you have two questions. Can you share your node setup?

Comment: thanks - removed part 2.

Comment: node setup:  image>keying>color spill>rgb curves>image>mix>>composite and viewer

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Answer (score 1):

Do this in the compositor.

Positioning the greenscreen element can be done with a Distort>Transform node, moving the Values for X and Y will give you control of Horizontal and Vertical.

Comment: it leaves a gap/hole where the clip was

Comment: You may have to crop it afterwards, removing from the right side the amount of right-shifting you did (works with left too)